# error al leer variables en JAVA

Tags: java, read

Me da error al leer variables, y se queda pillado en la segunda lectura de variables, coincidiendo con el entero. Es una aplicación con salida en modo texto. EL programa compila bien pero tiene estos tres errores.

Aquí dejo el código.

```
     package com.example.dias_vacaciones;
     import java.util.*;
     import java.text.*;
     import java.io.*;

   public class Vacaciones {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

       String nombre;
       int clave;
       int antiguedad;


       InputStreamReader teclado= new InputStreamReader(System.in);
       BufferedReader entrada = new BufferedReader (teclado);



       System.out.println("Introduce el nombre del empleado: ");
       nombre = entrada.readLine();

       System.out.println("Introduce la clave del empleado: ");
       clave = entrada.read();

       System.out.println("Introduce la antiguedad del empleado: ");
       antiguedad = entrada.read();


       if (clave == 1)
       {
           if (antiguedad == 1) {
               System.out.println("El empleado " + nombre + " tiene derecho a 6 días de vacaciones");
           }
           else if (antiguedad>=2 && antiguedad<=6) {
               System.out.println("El empleado " + nombre + " tiene derecho a 14 días de vacaciones");
           }
           else if (antiguedad>=7){
               System.out.println("El empleado " + nombre + " tiene derecho a 20 días de vacaciones");
           }
           else {
               System.out.println("El empleado aun no tiene derecho a vacaciones");
           }
       }
       else if (clave == 2)
       {
           if (antiguedad == 1) {
               System.out.println("El empleado " + nombre + " tiene derecho a 10 días de vacaciones");
           }
           else if (antiguedad>=2 && antiguedad<=6) {
               System.out.println("El empleado " + nombre + " tiene derecho a 20 días de vacaciones");
           }
           else if (antiguedad>=7){
               System.out.println("El empleado " + nombre + " tiene derecho a 30 días de vacaciones");
           }
           else {
               System.out.println("El empleado aun no tiene derecho a vacaciones");
           }
       }
       else {
           System.out.println("Clave Incorrrecta");
       }

   }
}
```

---

Declaro las variables y no se que pasa.

El error es (x 3 veces):

> error: unreported exception IOException; must be caught or declared to be thrown

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > error al leer variables en JAVA

El problema radica en la forma como funciona el método [read](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read--), debido a que, esta rutina retorna el código [ASCII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_extendido) del caracter introducido y esto se debe porque este método en realidad sirve para pedir un caracter al usuario.

**¿Por qué el método `read` es de tipo `int` y no `char`?**

Porque el método `read` retorna `-1` si llegara a encontrar el final del archivo y como sabemos, el tipo de dato `int` tiene un rango de `-2147486648` a `2147486647` números (básicamente esto es lo máximo que puede almacenar en un registro de memoria).

**¿Por qué el método `read` es de tipo `int` y no `short`?**

Porque esta rutina lee un rango de `0` a `65535` y en un tipo `short` no alcanzaría para guardar un número de este tipo, debido a que, solo admite un rango de `-32768` a `32767` (ver [Primitive Data Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)).

En fin, al momento de invocarse esta línea de código:

```java
clave = entrada.read();
```

El usuario podría ingresar por teclado el número `1`, pensaríamos que en la variable `clave` estará almacenado el `1` pero en realidad no, debido a que, tendrá guardado el código `ASCII` del caracter y en este caso es un `49`. Esa es la razón del porque en ningún momento la condición `clave == 1` nunca se cumplirán (porque `49` != `1`).

**Una posible solución** es usar el método `readLine` y convertir la cadena en un dato de tipo `int` a través del método [parseInt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)).

El código quedaría así:

```java
System.out.println("Introduce la clave del empleado: ");
clave = Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());
System.out.println("Introduce la antiguedad del empleado: ");
antiguedad = Integer.parseInt(entrada.readLine());
```

De este modo aseguramos que las variables `clave` y `antiguedad` tengan guardados números enteros y no el `código ASCII` de un caracter (como por ejemplo el `1`).

Comment: Gracias, ahora lo entiendo, realmente almacenaba el codigo ASCII y no el valor del buffer introducido. Ahora si funciona

Comment: @pmike De nada, espero que te haya servido y no olvides de marcar la respuesta que te sirvió.